# Angular CLI don't create project and require the npm@6

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When I execute `ng new first-project` it returns that:

```
npm version  detected. The Angular CLI temporarily requires npm version 6 while upstream issues are addressed.

Please install a compatible version to proceed (`npm install --global npm@6`).
For additional information and alternative workarounds, please see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957#issuecomment-775407654
```

All right, I already have backed to npm@6 and no resolve, always show that message. Also, I already have cleaned the cache but I cannot resolve.

I'm using Ubuntu
The Angular CLI version is 11

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ask your question in English or at [es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Are you sure that npm 6 is running? What does `npm -v` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.10.  Here are the steps I executed to resolve the problem:

1. Install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

   wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
2. Install node using nvm:

   nvm install node
3. Install angular/cli:

   npm install -g @angular/cli
4. Install npm@6:

   npm install --global npm@6
5. Clear cache:

   npm cache clean --force
6. Create the new app:

   ng new first-project

Comment: why not npm@7 + ?

Comment: Because that's the version that is recommended in the message that is displayed:
"npm version 7.5.3 detected. The Angular CLI temporarily requires npm version 6 while upstream issues are addressed.
Please install a compatible version to proceed (`npm install --global npm@6`)."